# View not getting redrawed

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a view that I need to move 102 points to the right to show a menu, so I just call a offset every new view call. It was working till some builds, we changed something that made the view break. Since I can't try to undo something that is fixing another thing, I need to patch the view.

When I print the view after applying the offset(with po self.view.frame), I can see the offset applied correctly, but the view doesn't show it to me unless I change it again(go to another screen or rotate the device).

```
func resizeAndOffset() {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.appDelegate()
        let offset = UIApplication.appDelegate().offset

        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(offset, 0, appDelegate.window!.frame.width-offset, appDelegate.window!.frame.height)
        //self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, offset, 0)

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(offset, 0, appDelegate.window!.frame.width-offset, self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height)
    }
```

This is where I resize and move the view.

```
func rotated() {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
            resizeAndOffset()
        }
    }
```

I call it every time the screen changes orientation.

And I also call the resize function on viewDidLoad() and viewDidAppear().

Is there anywhere else I should be calling it? Where I can force an entire screen redraw?

Comment: Did you try `setNeedsDisplay()`?

Comment: Is `resizeAndOffset` being called from the main thread?

Comment: @NoahWitherspoon I really don't know. Should I dispatch it from main queue? I'll try it.

Edit: Tried with `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {` without luck.

Answer (score 0):

Add setNeedsDisplay() to the bottom of your function:

```
func resizeAndOffset() {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.appDelegate()
    let offset = UIApplication.appDelegate().offset

    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(offset, 0, appDelegate.window!.frame.width-offset, appDelegate.window!.frame.height)
    //self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, offset, 0)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(offset, 0, appDelegate.window!.frame.width-offset, self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height)

    self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```